# Get client id of all durable clients connected to ActiveMQ broker

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is there a way/command to get list of all client id of all durable clients connected to ActiveMQ broker on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jconsole list all clientids connected to broker.

Connect to broker in jconsole

In Mbeans tag, go to org.apache.activemq.

Expand Broker -> clientConnectirs.

you will see bunch of different transport connector opened by broker. In these connector you can see clientId , expanding it will show all clientId for that connector.